# Angular2 clarifications

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have my first angular app based off the quickstart and [hero tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) that follows.

So my `app.component` handles the routing and the `app.component.html` is simply:

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

I want to add a navbar to the app.  I made a component.  The `navbar.component.html` looks like this:

```
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <h3 class="nav-title"><a href="stores">Title</a></h3>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li id="storesNavLink" class="" ><a href="stores">All Stores</a></li>
                <my-cart></my-cart>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should I add the navbar to my app.component as such:

```
<my-navbar></my-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>  ?
```

This ensures that the navbar is on every view but it obscures content from my other components.

Also, you'll notice, there's a cart on the navbar `<my-cart></my-cart>`.

The cart is a component I created and put in the navbar.

If the cart is in the navbar and the navbar is in the `app.component`, how will I add things to the cart from a `products.component` with an "add to cart" button?

Who, in this case is the child and who is the parent?

The tutorial was helpful but I've been unable to find anything on communication between components that aren't directly parent/child related.

I'm guessing it has something to do with a service.

Answer (score 0):

I think this syntax is correct.

```
<my-navbar></my-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If the navbar is on every view you have to put the components like this.
Don't worry about adding product to the cart, You can do it by input and out-put(emitter) property of angular 2.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've been looking for that information.  It never would have occurred to me to look under cookbook.  So why is the navbar hiding other component content, I figure it should push it down but it just sits on top.

Comment: Sorry i cant get you.